# unrecognized selector SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:center

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm creating an app using the sprite kit framework for ios 7. When testing on an iPhone 5s it works fine. However when testing on an iPad mini I keep getting an error: unrecognized selector SKPhysicsBody  bodyWithCircleOfRadius:center. The weird thing is though that all the other SKPhysicsBody methods work. For example both `[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:]` and `[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:]` work fine. It's only `[SKPhysicsBody  bodyWithCircleOfRadius:center:]` that fails, and only on the iPad. Thanks

Comment: That is really really weird !!!

Comment: SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:center was added in iOS 7.1. Your iPad mini must be running 7.0.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class reference says:

[bodyWithCircleOfRadius:center:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithCircleOfRadius:center:)

> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 7.1 and later.

So if that particular device runs iOS 7.0 or earlier the selector will be unrecognized.

Comment: ahh thanks, you're right. Better update deployment target to 7.1.